# Reading a particular key value from ansible facts

Tags: ansible

I was trying to pull out the below variable value from ansible fact (ansible_mount) as shown below.
I have a lot of mounts in the target machine. What I want is to retrieve only device key value where mount is equal to / . i.e, I want to retrieve device value for / mount point. How can I get it? I tried many things as per my knowledge, but not working out.

One more thing, I want to confirm is how would I check if any of the mount keys hold value /user from ansible_mount facts. This is to see if /usr is mounted as separate FS or it comes under / FS.

```
 "ansible_mounts": [
            {
                "block_available": 7800291, 
                "block_size": 4096, 
                "block_total": 8225358, 
                "block_used": 425067, 
                "device": "/dev/mapper/foobar", 
                "fstype": "xfs", 
                "inode_available": 16403366, 
                "inode_total": 16458752, 
                "inode_used": 55386, 
                "mount": "/", 
                "options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota", 
                "size_available": 31949991936, 
                "size_total": 33691066368, 
                "uuid": "2ebc82cb-5bc2-4db9-9914-33d65ba350b8"
            }, 
            {
                "block_available": 44648, 
                "block_size": 4096, 
                "block_total": 127145, 
                "block_used": 82497, 
                "device": "/dev/sda1", 
                "fstype": "xfs", 
                "inode_available": 255595, 
                "inode_total": 256000, 
                "inode_used": 405, 
                "mount": "/boot", 
                "options": "rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota", 
                "size_available": 182878208, 
                "size_total": 520785920, 
                "uuid": "c5f7eaf2-5b70-4f74-8189-a63bb4bee5f8"
            },
```

Comment: can anyone help on this? Is the information sufficient enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using loop and when condition.

To show all mount points (you can use it for any other action too

```
- name: Show only Mount point and device info
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
```

To show only specific mount points; eg "/". Other mount points will be skipped.

```
- name: Show only / Mount info
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.mount }} - {{ item.device }}"
  when: item.mount == '/'
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
```

Give a try

Update:
If you want to check and do action later, use variable and set_fact

```
- name: Check and set fact if / mount point exists
  set_fact:
    usr_mount_exist: true
  when: item.mount == '/'
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"

- name: Show if / exists
  debug:
    msg: "/ mount point exists"
  when: usr_mount_exist == true
```